# how to create dynamic nested array in React hook forms?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I making a form using React Hook Form.

I am trying to fulfill the nested dynamic array . Here, I've created a dynamic field for product that can be append and removed. Now I want to create a dynamic array (sizeNs) that can be append and removed

The Data I want to achieve when I Submit the form is below :

```
            const data = {
               name  : "",
              product: [
                {
                  color: 'black',
                  image: 'htpp..',
                  sizeNs: [
                    {
                      size: 'Small',
                      inStock: '10',
                    },
                    {
                      size: 'Medium ',
                      inStock: '10',
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  color: 'white',
                  image: 'htpp..',
                  sizeNs: [
                    {
                      size: 'Small',
                      inStock: '10',
                    },
                    {
                      size: 'Medium ',
                      inStock: '10',
                    },
 {
                      size: 'large ',
                      inStock: '10',
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
```

My Current Code :

```
       /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
    import { DevTool } from '@hookform/devtools'
    import { useEffect } from 'react'
    import { useForm, useFieldArray } from 'react-hook-form'
    
    let count = 0
    
    const ReactHook = () => {
      const form = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
          name: '',
          product: [{ color: '', image: null, sizeNs: [{ size: '', inStock: 1 }] }],
        },
      })
    
      const { register, control, formState, handleSubmit, reset } = form
      const { errors, isDirty, isSubmitting, isSubmitSuccessful } = formState
      const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        name: 'product',
        control,
      })
    
      const onSubmit = data => {
        console.log('Data', data)
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (isSubmitSuccessful) reset()
      }, [isSubmitSuccessful, reset])
    
      return (
        <div className='form-wrapper'>
          <div className='form-container'>
            <h5>Render - {count}</h5>
            <h2>Form</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
              <div className='form-control'>
                <label>
                  <span>Name : </span>
                  <input
                    type='text'
                    {...register('name', {
                      required: 'Name is Required',
                    })}
                  />
                  <p className='error'>{errors.name?.message}</p>
                </label>
              </div>
    
              <div>
                <label htmlFor='product'>Product Details</label>
                <div>
                  {fields.map((field, index) => {
                    return (
                      <div className='form-control d-flex' key={field.id}>
                        <label htmlFor='' className='mr-2'>
                          <span>Color:</span>
                          <select
                            {...register(`product.${index}.color`, {
                              required: 'color field is Missing',
                            })}
                          >
                            <option value=''>--Select Color</option>
                            <option value='black'>Black</option>
                            <option value='white'>White</option>
                            <option value='orange'>Orange</option>
                          </select>
    
                          <p className='error'>
                            {errors.product?.[index]?.color?.message}
                          </p>
                        </label>
    
                        <label htmlFor='' className='mr-2'>
                          <span>Image : </span>
                          <input
                            type='file'
                            {...register(`product.${index}.image`, {
                              required: 'Image field is Missing',
                              validate: {
                                lessThan2MB: value =>
                                  value[0]?.size < 200000 ||
                                  'File Size should be less than 200kb.',
    
                                acceptedFormats: files =>
                                  ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'].includes(
                                    files[0]?.type
                                  ) || 'Only PNG, JPEG e GIF',
                              },
                            })}
                          />
                          <p className='error'>
                            {errors.product?.[index]?.image?.message}
                          </p>
                        </label>
    
                        <label htmlFor=''>
                          <span>Size </span>
                          <select
                            {...register(`product.${index}.sizeNS.${index}.size`, {
                              required: 'size is required',
                            })}
                          >
                            <option value=''>--Select Size</option>
                            <option value='small'>S</option>
                            <option value='medium'>M</option>
                            <option value='large'>L</option>
                            <option value='extralarge'>XL</option>
                          </select>
                        </label>
    
                        <label htmlFor=''>
                          <span>In Stock :</span>
                          <input
                            type='number'
                            {...register(
                              `product.${index}.sizeNS.${index}.inStock`,
                              {
                                valueAsNumber: true,
                                required: 'In Stock is required',
                              }
                            )}
                          />
                        </label>
    
                        {index > 0 && (
                          <button type='button' onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                            Remove
                          </button>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    )
                  })}
    
                  <button
                    type='button'
                    onClick={() =>
                      append({
                        color: '',
                        image: null,
    
                        inStock: 1,
                      })
                    }
                    className='mt-m'
                  >
                    Add More
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
    
              <button
                type='submit'
                className='mt-m'
                disabled={!isDirty || isSubmitting}
              >
                {isSubmitting ? 'loading' : 'Submit'}
              </button>
    
              <button onClick={() => reset()}>Rest</button>
            </form>
            <DevTool control={control} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default ReactHook
```